# Disabling button and storing in database

Tags: android

I am calling same activity for 5, 6 different movies to book ticket. I have used button for seats. I set button disable after clicking and store its id in sql database. Now when I come again to book another ticket for same movie, same show

```
String[] projection= new String[]{
                movieEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SEAT
        };
        //where clause
        String selection=movieEntry.COLUMN_NAME_MN + " =?"+" AND "+movieEntry.COLUMN_NAME_MD +" =?" +" AND "+movieEntry.COLUMN_NAME_MT +" =?" ;
         // int i=0;
          String colindex=null;
          // this query is select seatno from tablename
        // where movie_name='movie that user selected' and movie_time='user seklected currently'
        //and movie_date='';
        //it is working correctly its fetching all records
        // i am trying to add all this fetched seatno to the seatsArraylist so that
        //we can get it from this arrayList and disable that seats for the user for that particular movie and date and time
        // but problem is that it is adding only one records to arraylist
        //can you plz go through this code
          String[] selectionArgs ={ Movietitle, Datem, Mtiming} ;
          try{
              Cursor cursor = rdb.query(
                      movieEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                      projection,
                      selection,
                      selectionArgs,
                      null,
                      null,
                      null
              );
              if(cursor!= null ) {
                   int i=0;
                  while(cursor.moveToFirst())
                  {
                    colindex= cursor.getString(i);
                      seatsArrayList.add(colindex);
                      i++;
                     tv1.setText(seatsArrayList.get(2));
                  }
                  tv.setText(colindex);
              }
             /* for(int j=0;j<=seatsArrayList.size();j++)
              {
                  if(seatsArrayList.get(j)=="Seat4")
                  {
                      theBtn[3].setEnabled(false);

                  }
              }*/
```

Comment: what is `i` ? you are increment it for every row but using it as column index ... do you know basic cursor api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to iterate in your cursor like that you have just made your cursor to move to the first part (0th). To iterate in a cursor its easy with a for loop like this:

```
for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
// all operations should be here
}
```

And again even inside the loop the method `cursor.getString(int)` the `int` passed is not the index of a cursor but it is a column index. In your table there may be multiple columns the first one is (0th) the second column is (1st). So you should pass column indexes.